# java9 windows bigger than java8 ones

Tags: java, swing, java-8, java-9

There is a difference between the two, I don't know how to address this.

java 8 : it's correct

[image: here]

but java9 it's bigger and even the pictures are pixellized:

[image: here]
the program's window is so big that it doesn't fit in the screen.

Please note that I use the substance look'n feel library:

in the main method I have this:

```
JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {

      StatesManager statesManager = new StatesManager(new BookList());
      BookWindow window = new BookWindow(statesManager);


      SubstanceLookAndFeel.setSkin(new CremeCoffeeSkin());



      window.pack();
      window.setVisible(true);
      window.setLocation(150, 100);
      window.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(1150, 900));
      window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

I don't want to get rid of substance.

thank you

Comment: Have you considered looking into substance's issue tracker / forum / support system if this is a known issue?

Comment: Does the same happen with another look&feel? Do you have any "enlarge fonts"/"magnifying lens" features activated in Windows that Java 9 might respect and Java 8 not? Notice how even the image seems to be larger than before.

Comment: No idea. There somewhere seems to be a 110% or such. Try things to approximate the original, the text field font; graphic hints (fractional fonts); doing `Ctrl +`/`Ctrl -`.

Comment: AFAIK they improved support for HiDPI in Java 9, so this is probably Java apply the UI scaling as configured under Display Settings, Scale and layout.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's addressed.
The thing to do, in windows 10, is to modify the default zoom : "Windows" key + I / System / "modify text, applications and other elements size" --> reduce from 125% to 100%.